# Storyboards and Table View Sections

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

I've noticed that in Storyboards, when dragging out a Table View object from the Library, you also get a chance to configure table view sections, and bunch of other options. For example, if the content is going to be static cells or dynamic prototypes, etc.

Here's a look at the Table View in Interface Builder (.storyboard file):

[image: Storyboard]

and here's how the Table View looks like in a .xib file:

[image: XIB]

So my question is - is it possible to configure/style (drag buttons, images, etc. into cells) a table view in a .xib file using Interface Builder or it can only be done programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Can be done either way.  I prefer doing it in IB as the layout is much easier when you can see what you are doing.  For dynamic prototypes, you only design a single cell and the contents will be populated in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.  With a Static Cell tableview, you can design the whole thing (many sections and many rows).  The requirement for a Static Cell tableview is that the class HAS to be of type UITableViewController, while for Dynamic Prototypes, it can be either a UITableViewController or (my preference for more flexibility) a UIViewController with a UITableView.

Hint - if this is a Static cell tableview and you only design a screen full of sections and rows, be sure to turn off scrolling for the tableview.

Comment: I still don't find a way to do it in IB. All I see is the static image (California, Florida, New York) and I can't modify it.

Comment: First question - are you wanting dynamic prototypes (your class populates the cell content) or a static cell?

Comment: Some cells will have static data, some will have dynamic, others - both.

Comment: You can't have it both ways on the same tableview.  Has to be one or the other.  You might want to do a little more research on how tableviews work.

Comment: Take a look at my second screenshot. I do not see a way to edit that - e.g. rename California, or add another section. It's just a static image IB is showing you just to remind you that the view is UITableView. But I can edit that very same UITableView if I'm using storyboards.